# Nothing showing in window FBTilengine

Tags: freebasic

I’ve been trying to prototype my game in FBTilengine, I copied the examples for rendering the background layers like here:

[repo](https://github.com/megamarc/FBTilengine)

However my background layers do not show in the window. The project compiles with no errors and the samples work fine, but when I copy and paste the samples with their assets into another directory they do not show after compiling. I’m using the provided dlls and bindings to keep from manually updating them since they are dated.